# Capistrano Rails Asset Precompile Error

Tags: capistrano, asset-pipeline

I have a Capistrano script which is deploying my app to an Amazon EC2 machine. It is failing when compiling assets:

```
* executing "cd -- /home/ec2-user/uc_social_server/releases/20130731161645 && RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets rake assets:precompile"
    servers: ["ec2-23-22-188-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com"]
    [ec2-23-22-188-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com] executing command
 ** [out :: ec2-23-22-188-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com] Could not find thread_safe-0.1.0 in any of the sources
 ** [out :: ec2-23-22-188-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-23-22-188-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com] Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
 ** [out :: ec2-23-22-188-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
    command finished in 591ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/ec2-user/uc_social_server/releases/20130731161645; true"
    servers: ["ec2-23-22-188-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com"]
    [ec2-23-22-188-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com] executing command
    command finished in 201ms
failed: "sh -c 'cd -- /home/ec2-user/uc_social_server/releases/20130731161645 && RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets rake assets:precompile'" on ec2-23-22-188-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding following to deploy.rb

```
require "bundler/capistrano"
require "rvm/capistrano"
before "deploy:assets:precompile", "bundle:install"
```

and following to Capfile

```
load 'deploy/assets'
```

and following to Gemfile

```
gem 'rvm-capistrano'
```

resolved the issue for me. If you are not using rvm, maybe you will not need to require rvm/capistrano or the rvm-capistrano gem.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your `Capfile`

```
require 'capistrano/bundler'
```